# Subcontrols not visible in custom control derived from another control

Tags: c#, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control by deriving from a [ZedGraphControl](http://zedgraph.sourceforge.net/documentation/html/T_ZedGraph_ZedGraphControl.htm)
I need to add a ProgressBar to the control, but I encountered some problems.

When I create a custom control and add both, ZedGraphCOntrol and ProgressBar to it, everything is OK:

```
MyCustomControl
{
    ZedGraphControl
    ProgressBar
}
```

All elemnets are visible and working as expected.

But I need to derive from ZGC and when I add a progress bar as a subcontrol of ZedGraphControl:

```
MyCustomControl : ZedGRaphControl
{
   ProgressBar
}
```

The progress bar is not visible.

Is there any way to force the visibility of ProgressBar? Is it possible, that ZedGraphControl is not displaying its subcontrols? I tried do the same thing with a simple button and it's also not being displayed.

Comment: You should post your edit as an answer and then accept it.

Comment: Thank you, Jeff. I will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it seems that I solved the problem... 
There must be a call to the `InitializeComponent()` method in the Control's constructor.
When I was creating a custom control, it was added by default by the VS. But while deriving from ZedGraphControl I was creating the constructor from scratch, and that's why the subcontrols were not visible.

So the question can be closed.